# SQL: Need to get aggregrated status by priority across related tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Parent table A in MySQL DB 5.5.x  with columns

```
  Id(PK)  Name   Value
  1       ABC     0.1
  2       XYZ     0.2
  3       PQR     0.3
```

And a related table B which reference Id from parent (FK)
status can have only 3 possible values i.e. pass,warn,error
with error check being higher priority than warn and so on

```
  CheckName  CheckStatus  Id
   L1         pass        1
   L2         pass        1
   L3         warn        1
   L4         error       1
   L1         pass        2
   L2         warn        2
   L3         pass        2
```

I want to create an SQL statement which can get aggregrate result from parent table A such that

if Id 1 has any errors reported against it I label the finalState for Id 1 as ERROR,

if no errors found check if Id 1 has any warnings reported against it and label the finalState as WARN

finally Mark it as pass.

I am unable to do a simple JOIN or add a case statement in the select claues
as i start getting multiple rows here.

Can I do this without using Stored Procedures ?.

**Result Expected based on sample data in final select query is as follows**:-

```
Id  Name  FinalStatus
1   ABC   error
2   XYZ   warn
```

Thanks!

EDIT: 
Approach 1 (That I tried here):

```
select a.Id, 
   case when b.CheckStatus='error' then 'ERROR'
  case when b.CheckStatus='warn' then 'WARN'
  case when b.CheckStatus='pass' then 'PASS'             
 from a join b on
a.Id=b.Id
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks Strawbeery1, I am very new to SQL and tried to google some approaches but was unable to see how i can get a single row with aggregrated status as i ubale to achieve it with JOINS.

Comment: Sry i am new to dev forums can you sugget what i am missing in the above question so I can correct the content ?.

Comment: Do you want me to provide the approach i tried to resolve this and that didnot work ?.

Comment: I just want you to have a great day. The rest is optional.

Comment: ok, i edited my post with an approach i tried to implement with my limited understanding of that concept, need some help if possible

Comment: if anyone can point me to some useful link to address this issue would be great, thanks all experts !

Comment: With which part of the accepted answer at the linked question are you struggling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a prioritization query.  I am only focusing on `b` -- you can bring in the columns from `a` using a simple join.

This works in MySQL 8+:

```
select b.*
from (select b.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by case checkstatus
                                             when 'error' then 1
                                             when 'warn' then 2
                                             when 'pass' then 3
                                             else 4
                                         end
                               ) as seqnum
      from b
     ) b
where seqnum = 1;
```

In earlier versions, I would go for conditional aggregation:

```
select b.id,
       max(finalstatus = 'error') as is_error,
       max(finalstatus = 'warn') as is_warn,
       max(finalstatus = 'pass') as is_pass
from b
group by b.id;
```

You can then get the final status as:

```
select b.id,
       (case when max(checkstatus = 'error') > 0 then 'error'
             when max(checkstatus = 'warn') > 0 then 'warn'
             when max(checkstatus = 'pass') > 0 then 'pass'
        end) as finalstatus
from b
group by b.id;
```

Comment: Gordon, Thanks a lot you made my day :)

Comment: I had ended up using a blotched coalesce query to create a matrix and than use java code to decipher the aggr status.. by scanning the output.